# I can use bp_get_activity_content_body() on entry.php but how to use on other

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I can use `bp_get_activity_content_body()` on `entry.php`
but how can i use it on bp-core-template.php

Sorry for my poor question, i’m very new for php editor.

Comment: No source code no talk. Have you include your function lib in php file?

Answer (score 1):

bp-core-template.php is one of the core files of BuddyPress and that makes it a bad idea to edit the file. Whenever you update Buddypress there is a good chance your changes will be overwritten.

If you are trying to alter the result of a function found in bp-core-template.php then you will want to use one of the filters in that function to safely alter the content "the wordpress way".

So if you want to change the output of the function bp_create_excerpt found on line 877 of bp-core-template.php you could use the filter bp_create_excerpt in the functions.php file of your theme.

In functions.php (example modified from hookr.io):

```
// define the bp_create_excerpt callback 
function filter_bp_create_excerpt( $text, $original_text, $length, $options ) { 

    if ( function_exists( bp_get_activity_content_body )
        $text = bp_get_activity_content_body();

    return $text; 
};

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'bp_create_excerpt', 'filter_bp_create_excerpt', 10, 4 );
```

EDIT: It should be noted that I do not know what bp_get_activity_content_body() will return in this context and I would probably just return $original_text if I didn't want a truncated excerpt. My intent is to highlight how you should be changing output of things from a plugin's core files.